# Wordpress API call consistently rejects requests on CORS

Tags: wordpress, cors, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, wordpress-rest-api

I'm sending an http request (in my case, from my Angular app), using Wordpress's Application Password (basically an API token).

I am getting this CORS rejection error in the browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mors.sg-host.com/get-current-user.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

[image]

My Wordpress is hosted with SiteGround, and with their support agent we tried several things, to no avail.

We added these rules to the .htaccess file to allow CORS and disable the dynamic caching:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "private"
</IfModule>
```

I also tried a Wordpress pluging (*Http Headers*) that essentially added similar CORS statements to the .htaccess file.

My Angular client call looks like this:

```
export class WpGetCurrentUserService {

  private apiUrl = 'https://mors.sg-host.com/wp-json';
  private accessToken = 'uN...UU';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization')
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`);

    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/wp/v2/users/me`, { headers });
  }
}
```

**Please, what am I missing here?**